# Traefik: Load balance internal service without exposing it outside

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, traefik

Currently, I have a `frontend`, `backend`, and `tf-serving` service. My current configuration exposes both `frontend` and `backend` services outside.

The service `tf-serving`, however, is an internal service only used by the `backend` service. They communicate using the gRPC API provided by TensorFlow Serving.

Would it be possible for `tf-serving` to be load balanced too such that when I call it from the `backend` service, Traefik will load balance it for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. A better approach however, is to connect tf-serving service to the same network as your backend service (or create a separate network just for the two of them) and connect to it directly from backend using container name dns resolving.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I recently read that docker swarm automagically load balances internal services so i can just connect to it directly without any changes (I previously thought that I was just connecting to one container).